# How to Align ViewPagerIndicator to Bottom of Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator and I want to align the indicator to the bottom of the screen. I'm running into these problems however.

## My Code

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hidden.hidden"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/indicator" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now this layout makes the following layout:
[image: Indicator aligned to top]

That's great but I want make the indicator go at the bottom below the text and anything else I might put in the fragment layout.

I tried changing `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but that just gives me something like this:
[image]

The position is perfect but from my understanding of layouts, it seems that the fragment text is now below the indicator and off-screen.

Here is one of three fragment layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text will go here!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There are two more like these but don't need to be posted.

Is there any way to make the indicator it's own layout on the bottom of the screen and have the fragment text be above it? I did some searching on here but found nothing that related to the ViewPagerIndicator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use LinearLayout. Check my answer below. I have successfully put the indicator at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this set attribute in `indicator` **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** and in `viewpager` **android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hidden.hidden"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/indicator" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To be better, pager should align: android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Answer (score 1):

```
    Try to align at the bottom of viewpager


  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code Below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.crm.dealerportal"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.crm.isf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:padding="5dip"
        app:gapWidth="20dip"
        app:lineWidth="40dip"
        app:selectedColor="@color/actionBarBG"
        app:strokeWidth="7dp"
        app:unselectedColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using relative layout in parent.which has a property of :

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

just add this to your viewpager indicator widget  like:

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="10dip"
    app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

will set indicator at the bottom of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hidden.hidden"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
        />


    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
            app1:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

            />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help!